# Yii2: PHPExcel error when process Excel contain 90k rows

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel

I have an application that has upload Excel file process. Then PHPExcel will process the uploaded Excel file.

This is the flow of process:

- Upload file
- Save file into local directory
- Get file from local dir
- Read the file using PHPExcel

I've successfully save the Excel file to local directory, reading and get the data from the Excel file.

But when I use an Excel file that contain **90K of rows x 25 columns**, that file didn't saved into local directory. Then I'm trying to `print_r` the data and it return `error=> 1`

This is the print_r result

**1. Excel with less than 8k rows and successfully saved to local dir:**

[image]

**2. Excel with 90K of rows and didn't saved into local dir:**

[image]

#### This is my code in controller

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    $model = new MasterProduct();
    $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;

    $date = new DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Bali'));
    $created_at = $date->format('Y:m:d H:i:s');

    $dirTrash = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash');
    $dirSubTrash = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app');

//create directory in local if doesn't exist
    if (!is_dir($dirTrash)) {
        mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash'));
        if (!is_dir($dirSubTrash)) {
            mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app'));
        }
    } else {
        if (!is_dir($dirSubTrash)) {
            mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app'));
        }
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $result = [];
        $fileMaster = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('master_product');
        $middleName = substr(md5(microtime() * 100000), rand(0, 9), 5);

    //named the uploaded file, then save into local directory
        if ($fileMaster !== null) {
            $nameMaster = $userId . '_MP' . '_' . $middleName . '_' . date('Y-m-d') . '_' . $fileMaster[0]->getBaseName() . "." . $fileMaster[0]->getExtension();
            $pathMaster = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app/') . $nameMaster;
            $fileMaster[0]->saveAs($pathMaster);
            
        } else {
            $error[] = "Choose the" . "<strong>" . " Excel " . "</strong>" . "file first.";
            $result = [
                'error' => $error
            ];
        }

    //this the code i've used to print_out the array in above images
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($fileMaster);
        die();  

    //Access, and get the data from local directory
        $objPHPExcelMaster = new \PHPExcel();
        $fileNameMaster = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app/') . $nameMaster;
        $inputFilesMaster = fopen(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/trash/trash_app/') . $nameMaster, "r");
        try {
            $inputFileTypeMaster = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fileNameMaster);
            $objReaderMaster = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileTypeMaster);
            $objPHPExcelMaster = $objReaderMaster->load($fileNameMaster);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die('Error');
        }
        $sheetMaster = $objPHPExcelMaster->getSheet(0);
        $highestRowMaster = $sheetMaster->getHighestDataRow();
        $highestColumnMaster = $sheetMaster->getHighestDataColumn();
     
    //read the Excel file and set into array
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRowMaster; ++$row) {
            $rowDataMaster = $sheetMaster->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumnMaster . $row, NULL, TRUE, NULL);
        }

        $tempDataMaster = mysql_escape_string(json_encode($rowDataMaster));

        $commandCheckExist = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `gm_json_master` WHERE id=$userId";
        $queryCheckExist = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($commandCheckExist)->execute();         
    
    //save data into db
        if ($queryCheckExist == 0) {
            $command_2 = "INSERT INTO json_master(json_m_product) VALUES('$tempDataMaster')";
            $query_2 = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($command_2)->execute();
        } else {
            $commandUpdate = "UPDATE json_master SET json_m_product='$tempDataMaster'";
            $queryUpdate = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($commandUpdate)->execute();
        }

        $result = [
            'url' => Url::to(['/gm/json-master-product/save'])
        ];
        return $result;
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How does this happen? and how do I can read big data of Excel using PHPExcel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error code of 1 means that the file size exceeds the max filesize allowed by your server's configuration.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>   Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I would try upping that limit as well as the max POST size limit and see if that helps.

Comment: I got another issue, I've configure the php set inside php script, such as set `upload_max_filesize = 8M`, and I'm trying to upload Excel file that contain 48910 rows of data, but I got error "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)" and "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" so I set `memory_limit=512M` and `max_execution_time=240`, but the PHPExcel only can access data and set into array until index 38485. Do you know why this happen? I've tried increase the max_execution_time and memory_limit but it doesn't solve it. Thanks